# unable to set delegate and call method

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, storyboard

I created a delegate to pass data back to previous view controller after dismissing the current view controller.

this is how I am setting the delegate in

**PaymentViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)techProcessAction:(id)sender
{
TechProcessPaymentVC *techVC = [[TechProcessPaymentVC alloc]init];
[techVC setTechDelegate:self];
 NSLog(@"DELEGATE == %@",techVC.techDelegate);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"techProcess" sender:nil];
}
```

I can see that the delegate is set

```
Snap2Door[1765:1c703] DELEGATE == <PaymentDetailViewController: 0x9d3a360>
```

but when I check it in `TechProcessPaymentVC`'s `viewDidLoad` I'm getting `DELEGATE == (null)`

I guess this is the reason my callback method is not called which is in `PaymentViewController.m`.

this is how I defined the delegate in `TechProcessPaymentVC.h`

```
@protocol techProcessDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) techProcessViewControllerDismissed:(NSString *)paymentStatus;
@end

@interface TechProcessPaymentVC : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
{
id techDelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<techProcessDelegate>    techDelegate;
```

and this is how I am trying to call the method which is present in `PaymentViewController.m`

```
if ([[substrings objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"failure"]) {
        [self.techDelegate techProcessViewControllerDismissed:@"failure"];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: have you synthesized your delegate property?

Comment: yes, though I don't think this is necessary as XCode automatically does that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't ever *do* anything with `techVC`. You allocate it, assign its delegate, then let it go out of scope (it'll be deallocated in ARC or leaked otherwise).

Try the following: First, remove the instantiation and assignment from `techProcessAction:`. Second, implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` and then assign `self` to be the `techDelegate` of the segue's `destinationViewController`. Your methods will look something like the following "code" (which I typed from memory and didn't try to compile):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"techProcess"]) {
        ((TechProcessPaymentVC *)segue.destinationViewController).techDelegate = self;
    }
}

-(IBAction)techProcessAction:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"techProcess" sender:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` gets called when you `init` the `TechProcessPaymentVC` instance. Delegate gets set after that. Hence it is `nil`. Modify your `init` method to `initWithDelegate` and then assign the `delegate` and use it in `viewDidLoad`.

**EDIT**

Code:

**TechProcessPaymentVC.h**

```
@interface TechProcessPaymentVC : UIViewController

- (id) initWithDelegate:(id<techProcessDelegate>)delegate;

@end
```

**TechProcessPaymentVC.m**

```
#import "TechProcessPaymentVC.h"

@implementation TechProcessPaymentVC

- (id) initWithDelegate:(id<techProcessDelegate>)delegate {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.techDelegate = delegate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Modify your call

```
-(IBAction)techProcessAction:(id)sender
{
    TechProcessPaymentVC *techVC = [[TechProcessPaymentVC alloc]initWithDelegate:self];
    //....
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how to do that..can you please provide me some code?

Comment: thanks @Amar but still getting `Null` in `viewDidLoad`,Though I get it in `initWithDelegate:` and not able to call the method in `PaymentViewController`.

Comment: @Ankur Can you remove the ivar `id techDelegate;` that you are declaring in `TechProcessPaymentVC` class? Just the property declaration is sufficient. Try this and let me know.

Comment: no luck, still not working. does it depends on the fact that I am using ` [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"techProcess" sender:nil];` after `TechProcessPaymentVC *techVC = [[TechProcessPaymentVC alloc]initWithDelegate:self];`?

Answer (score 0):

If your destination view controller is wrapped into a navigation controller, you have to refer to it differently in prepareForSegue:

```
UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
DetailViewController *dvc = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score -3):

In TechProcessPaymentVC.h:

```
@interface TechProcessPaymentVC : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    id techDelegate_;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<techProcessDelegate> techDelegate;
@end
```

In TechProcessPaymentVC.m:

```
@implementation TechProcessPaymentVC
@synthesize techDelegate = techDelegate_;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", techDelegate_);
}
.
.
.
@end
```

Hope it's work for you!!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very helpful. What difference would an ivar make to the user in this case?